# HttpContext.User.Identity.Name is sometimes empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin

I'm using OWIN for authentication in ASP.NET MVC 5.

My project works perfectly in localhost with IIS Express.  The problem is when I upload the project in a web server.

I log in and the application works fine for a moment. Then, it seems as if the session has expired. The HttpContext.User.Identity.Name is empty.

This is my action filter:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{            
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name))
    {
        context.Result = new RedirectResult("authentication");
        return;
    }
}
```

and this is my login

```
 public JsonResult Login(LoginModel input)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if(_AuthenticationLogica.ChecarUsuario(input.User, input.Pass))
            {
                int idUser = _AuthenticationLogica.GetIdUser(input.User);
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, input.Usuario), new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, idUsuario+"") },DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,ClaimTypes.Name, ClaimTypes.Role);
                foreach (var item in _UsuariosLogica.GetPermissionUser(idUser))
                {
                    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, item.IdDerecho + ""));
                }
                var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
                // Set current principal
                Thread.CurrentPrincipal = claimsPrincipal;
                // if you want roles, just add as many as you want here (for loop maybe?)
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "guest"));
                // tell OWIN the identity provider, optional
                // identity.AddClaim(new Claim(IdentityProvider, "Simplest Auth"));
                int id = _AuthenticationLogica.ObtenerIdUsuario("jcsoto");
                Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    IsPersistent = true
                }, identity);

                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(input.Usuario, true);
                return Json(new { Resultado = 0, Mensaje = "Ready", IdUser = idUser });
            }
        }

        return Json(new { Resultado = 1, Mensaje = "User or pass wrong" });
    }
```

Comment: if session expires, then the user is no longer authenticated. is that not normal behaviour?

Comment: is your Application pool recycling for some reason?

Comment: Default Session Timeout is 20 minutes. If you want longer than that, you can configure in web.config.

Comment: @muratgu my timeout is 60 minutes but the session expires sometimes in one minute more less.

Comment: im not using pool recycling, i dont know what is that @GabrielGM

Comment: Is your session cookie still in your browser when the authentication expires?

Comment: yes, the cookie is still in the browser @GabrielGM

Comment: what do you use as session state mode?

Comment: i found the solution, you were right with your question about pool recycling, the server configuration had enabled recycle each determined number of http requests, thank you so much @GabrielGM

Comment: here is a link to better understand IIS app pool recycles : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614447/what-can-cause-iis-app-pool-to-recycle. Even though it's IIS 6, it's still valid.